# Why getting 403 - Forbidden Error with ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

Unable to understand what is the problem ? frequently getting 403 Error.

Within our server we have 2 to 4 MVC site, but few of them working properly with .NET Target Framework 4 (VS 2010)

But getting 403 Error most of the site Running .NET Target Framework 4.5 (VS **2013**). When ever we deploy a new publish we get 403 error, when we try to access the site. But when we reset user permission, site is running properly for couple of hours but after few hours same 403 Error.

[image]

I tried to with `aspnet_regiis -i` . But no luck.

In **Web.Config**

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

**User Permission**

(IIS_IUSRS) have full access

(Adminstrator) have full access

(Application Developer) have full access

(System) have full access

(User) have limited access

**Authentication**

Anonymous Authentication : Enabled

Forms Authentication : Enabled

**Note:** All other disabled

Comment: enable customerror mode off to track exact problem

Comment: @KamleshArya it is unable to access web site resource, so web.config unable to provide any specific error.